# How to get back to saved progress in single player in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

I had gotten to about 85% of the story in Dying Light when a buddy invited me to join him in his game. He was about 2%. So I joined him and now that I have finished playing with him, I can not get back to my last saved game. I keep starting a 2%, even if I'm in Single Player mode.

I've tried restarting the game and changing from multiplayer mode to single player mode, but every time I launch the game, I start back at 2%. There's no option to choose which game you want to continue, or load a past saved game.

Note, there's no "save" or "load" mechanism in this game for the player. It uses checkpoints and you just pickup where you left off.

Is there any way to get back to my game?

Comment: This is very strange, your progress shouldn't have been saved. Did you check to see if you can manually load an earlier save? Are you still in multiplayer mode? Check the advanced settings. Did you try restarting the game? Not going to lie, this is an older issue and has been patched - hopefully you didn't lose your progress.

Comment: @Xander thanks for your comments. I updated my question. I believe Steam updates the app continuously, so I should be used patched version. Can you explain how this supposed to work? Can you be playing two different story lines (one multi, one single player) at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common bug.

A workaround, as offered by [someone](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239140/discussions/0/1699415798776437067/#c1699415798777283317) on the Steam forums, is to not 'Continue' the bugged saved game, but, instead, select 'Play' in the main menu, and choose the correct saved game file there:

> What I've noticed now, after logging on earlier, is that there was a
>   3rd *.SAV* file somewhere, connected to the server side of things. Most
>   times, 'Continue' loads the correct *.SAV*, except when a multiplayer server is
>   involved [..] It loads some
>   obscure, hidden *.SAV* file. I only have been able to find two *.SAV* files
>   in my asset tree; my *BTZ.SAV* and my *COOP.SAV* files. I'm assuming that
>   these are the files referenced when logging on. I'm assuming the
>   *COOP.SAV* file is my last saved game on log off, when you exit the game
>   environment with 'QUIT'.
>
> When I logged on, I was presented with the 'Continue' menu choice;
>   doing so put me back some *.SAV* file when I was in a joined server; not
>   part of any save I wanted. Selecting 'Play' gave me the Campaign option,
>   which was my last correct *COOP.SAV* file. Selecting 'The Following' gave
>   me my correct *.SAV* file in that branch.
>
> Once I entered the game environment and did some things, then quit,
>   I was presented with the correct *.SAV* file with the
>   'Continue' menu choice. So, for me, **the take-a-way is to NOT choose
>   the 'Continue' play choice after engaging in MP gameplay; instead,
>   enter Play and then choose the correct *.SAV* point from either the Campaign
>   or The Following menu choices.**